# Generate Group ID with 2 conditions in Stata

Tags: panel, stata, uniqueidentifier

I need to assign a unique ID to each person every 62 observations. In the example below, every row with `siteid` from 1 to 62 and `visits`=3 would refer to person 1, every row with `siteid` from 1 to 62 and `visits`=1 would refer to person 2, etc. I tried

```
  egen newid=group(siteid visits)
```

and

```
  by siteid: gen uniqueid = 1 if _n==1
  replace uniqueid = sum(uniqueid)
```

but none of these yield the desired results.

```
siteid

1
2
3
4
...
62
1
2
3
4
...
62
1
2
3
4
...
62
```

and so on

```
visits

3
3
3
3
...
3
1
1
1
1
...
1
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You just want the first 62 observations to be assigned 1, the next 62 to be assigned 2, and so forth. That is done by

```
egen uniqueid = seq(), block(62)
```

The important detail here is that this command makes no reference to any of the existing variables. Their precise values are irrelevant. But you could go

```
gen uniqueid = sum(siteid == 1)
```

to achieve the same effect. You score 1 every time `siteid` is 1, getting blocks of 1 followed by 61 zeros, and their cumulative sum from `sum()` is then blocks of 1s, 2s, etc.

Comment: Yes! sorry -- I rewrote the var name before posting and forgot to replace one var name, but you did understand me because that's exactly what I wanted STATA to do. I don't know how to get my columns to show as columns when I type on here -- they show up as rows. Hence, my attempt to clarify by adding "row vectors." Thanks for you help! Hopefully my edited post can help some readers, too.

Comment: Thanks. Please see also http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/resources/statalist-faq/#spell

Comment: If your question is answered, you can accept the answer. You will gain some reputation thereby.